# If $(2+\sqrt 3)\cos x=1-\sin x$ then x=?

Tags: trigonometry

The equation is 
$$\tan\frac{5\pi}{6} \cos x=1-\sin x$$
$$\sin\frac{5\pi}{6} \cos x=\cos\frac{5\pi}{6}-\cos\frac{5\pi}{6} \sin x$$
$$\sin\left(\frac{5\pi}{6}+x\right)=\cos \frac{5\pi}{6}$$ which looks weird to me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why weird? $x=\pi/2$ works right?

Comment: But isn’t sin equal to cos only when $x=\pi /4$

Comment: $\sin(\pi/4) = \cos(\pi/4)$. Also $\sin(x+\pi/2) = \cos(x)$. Moving the graph of $\sin(x)$ to left by $\pi/2$ gives $\cos(x)$. See [this in desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/uyzr9hnavf)

Comment: The equation at your title and in your question don't match. They will give you different results. Which one are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note $\tan\frac{5\pi}{12}=2+\sqrt3$ to rewrite $(2+\sqrt 3)\cos x=1-\sin x$ as

$$\sin\frac{5\pi}{12}\cos x+\cos\frac{5\pi}{12}\sin x=\cos\frac{5\pi}{12}$$

or

$$\sin\left(\frac{5\pi}{12}+x\right)=\sin\frac{\pi}{12}\implies2\cos\left(\frac x2+\frac\pi4\right)\sin\left(\frac x2+\frac\pi6\right)=0$$

which yields $x=2k\pi-\frac\pi3$ and $x=2k\pi +\frac\pi2$.

Comment: I think it would be better if you stick to radians for consistency reasons.

Comment: @johnny09 - Noted. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another way and probably a better one,

$$2+\sqrt3=\csc30+\cot30=\dfrac{1+\cos30}{\sin30}=\cot(?)=\tan(?)$$

Use  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution to find

$$\dfrac{1-\sin x}{\cos x}=\tan(45^\circ-x/2)$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\theta = \frac{5 \pi}{6}$. Then continuing from where you stopped and noting that $\cos(\theta) = -\frac{\sqrt(3)}{2}$, we get
$$\sin(\theta + x) = \cos(\theta)
= -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
and so,
$$\theta + x = \arcsin\left(-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right) = -\frac{\pi}{3}.$$
Thus, $x = - \frac{7 \pi}{6}$.

Answer (score 0):

One set of solutions is given by $\cos x = 0$ and $\sin x = 1$, i.e.:
$$
x = \left(2n + \tfrac12\right)\pi.
$$

If $\cos x \ne 0$, then $\sin x \ne 1$, and
$$
\left(2 - \sqrt3\right)\cos x = \frac{\cos^2 x}{\left(2 + \sqrt3\right)\cos x} =
\frac{1 - \sin^2 x}{1 - \sin x} = 1 + \sin x,
$$
whence, by adding and subtracting the two equations,  $\cos x = \tfrac12$ and $\sin x = -\sqrt3\cdot\cos x = -\tfrac{\sqrt3}2$, i.e.:
$$
x = \left(2n - \tfrac13\right)\pi.
$$